# cmake repeats the CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX until error

Tags: c++, cmake, installation, swig

```
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/home/usr/bin" ..
make install
```

give

```
-- Installing: /home/wsmith/bin/include/cms_xl/include/cms_xl/build/bin/include/cms_xl/build/bin..
```

**repeated until ...**

```
ld/bin/include/cms_xl/build/bin/include/cms_xl/build/bin/include/cms_xl/build/bin/include/cms_xl/build/bin/include/cms_xl/build/bin/include/cms_xl/build/bin/include/cms_xl":
  File name too long
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake_install.cmake:58 (include)
```

base- 
   -swig
   -src

File contents CMakeLists.txt on base:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

add_subdirectory(/home/wsmith/cmake/src/cms_xl/src)
add_subdirectory(/home/wsmith/cmake/src/cms_xl//swig)

install (TARGETS zoo  RUNTIME DESTINATION bin LIBRARY DESTINATION lib)
```

swig dir CMakeLists.txt looks like

```
project(zoo)

include(log4cpp)
include(mysql)
include(boost)
include(perl)
include(swig)
include(setup)

set(PATH_TO_CMS_SOURCE /home/wsmith/cmake/src/cms_xl/src/)
if (NOT DEFINED CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX)
  set(install_override ON)
else (NOT DEFINED CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX)
  set(install_override OFF)
endif (NOT DEFINED CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX)

include_directories(${PATH_TO_PERL} ${PATH_TO_CMS} ${PATH_TO_CMS_SOURCE})

swig_create(zoo)

set_target_properties( zoo  PROPERTIES RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
install (TARGETS zoo  RUNTIME DESTINATION bin LIBRARY DESTINATION lib)
```

swig.cmake (include ):

```
function(swig_create arg)
        FIND_PACKAGE(SWIG REQUIRED)
        INCLUDE(${SWIG_USE_FILE})
        #swig_link_libraries(${PERL_LIBRARIES})

        SET(CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS "-Wall" "-c++")
        set_source_files_properties(${arg}.i PROPERTIES CPLUSPLUS ON)
        set_source_files_properties(${arg}.i PROPERTIES SWIG_FLAGS "-c++;-shadow")
        set_property(SOURCE ../swig/${arg}.i PROPERTY CPLUSPLUS ON)
        swig_add_library( ${arg} LANGUAGE perl SOURCES ../swig/${arg}.i )
        target_include_directories(${arg} PRIVATE ${PATH_TO_CMS_SOUCE})
endfunction()
```

It works if I go to the swig dir and do a cmake . , make install 
but if I try from the base or from the build it repeats the

Comment: This path `<something>/include/<something>/include/<something>` (note triple `include`) indicates that something is wrong with your project. Such path should contain only one `include`. Please provide more context add more comment show more relevant contents of cmake code.

Comment: I've tried make your question readable, with limited information you provided. Maybe first you should read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Now I put only one include and still the issue persists. I am a newbie to cmake.

Comment: Note that path in error message has repeating pattern `/bin/include/cms_xl/build/`. Apparently you have some dependency cycle or loop which creates this path recurring path. Problem is that your question do not contain `/bin/include/cms_xl` so still not enough information to help you. Also do not use absolute paths in CMake! I doubt someone else has path `/home/wsmith/`